# Is it possible to only have a ComputedProperty for certain entities?

Tags: google-app-engine, properties, app-engine-ndb

In my application I have a model like so:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
    entity_key_list = ndb.KeyProperty('k', repeated=True, indexed=False)
    entity_key_num = ndb.ComputedProperty('n', lambda self: len(self.entity_key_list))
    verified = ndb.BooleanProperty('v')
```

Is it possible to have the entity_key_num property when verified is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return `None` if not `verified` like this:

```
entity_key_num = ndb.ComputedProperty('n', lambda self: len(self.entity_key_list) if not self.verified else None)
```

If you don't want to have the value `None` at all and dynamically delete or create this property then you will have to use the [`ndb.Expando`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass#Introduction) class where you can do all these fancy stuff. Note that you won't be able to delete the `ComputedProperty` so you will have to keep track of that value on your own.

Comment: The question is weather it will add it with 'n'=None or with no 'n' property at all.
PS: I'm doing this to save space